# Why does it keep telling me too few parameters?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()
    Dim Category As String
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Get the selected category from the combo box
    Category = ComboBox1.Value
    
    'Open the recordset for the selected category
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Category = '" & Category & "'")
    
    'Clear the Inventory sheet
    Worksheets("Inventory").Cells.ClearContents
    
    'Copy the data to the Inventory sheet
    Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A1").Value = "Product Name"
    Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B1").Value = "Supplier Name"
    Worksheets("Inventory").Range("C1").Value = "Unit Price"
    Worksheets("Inventory").Range("D1").Value = "Units In Stock"
    
    rowCount = 2
    
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A" & rowCount).Value = rs("ProductName").Value
        Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B" & rowCount).Value = rs("SupplierName").Value
        Worksheets("Inventory").Range("C" & rowCount).Value = rs("UnitPrice").Value
        Worksheets("Inventory").Range("D" & rowCount).Value = rs("UnitsInStock").Value
        
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    'Calculate and display the total cost of inventory
    Dim totalCost As Double
    totalCost = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Inventory").Range("C2:C" & rowCount - 1))
    
    MsgBox "Total Cost of Inventory for " & Category & ": $" & totalCost
    
    'Unload the userform
    Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    'Unload the userform
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub InventoryCalculationButton_Click()
    'Show the userform
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Specifically, this part of the code

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Category = '" & Category & "'")
```

I tried everything but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Could the variable `Category` have an apostrophe in it? If so, modify the WHERE like this:  `WHERE Category = '" & Replace(Category, "'", "''") & "'")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8422953/brax sadly it didnt work

Comment: Did Category have an apostrophe in it tho? When it errors and stops, you can check the value of your variables. Did you do that? What is the exact value of your `Category` variable when it errors? Also, where are you getting `CurrentDb`? That's an Access thing, not an Excel thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look on this site and all VBA-related questions, mentioning `CurrentDb` are about MS-Access.

A quick Google brought me on [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.currentdb), which clearly mentions that `CurrentDb` is MS-Access technology indeed, so you cannot simply use this in an Excel-VBA macro: as you can see, `CurrentDb` is an abbreviation of `access.application.currentdb` (not `excel.application.currentdb`).